# visual c++ cross platform android: Include prebuilt shared library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm using the Visual C++ Cross Platform Tools for Android as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn707591.aspx

Everything works fine so far (I can build and run on my phone the templates under File -> New Project -> Cross Platform -> Android). However, **I can't find out how to link my app to a prebuilt shared library in the form of an *.so file**.

So far, I tried the following steps:

**Step 1**

To test the ability of Visual Studio to link to a prebuilt shared library, I created a small shared library as follows:

SharedLibrary.cpp:

```
#include "SharedLibrary.h"

const char * SharedLibrary::GetString()
{
    return "Hello from Shared Library";
}

void SharedLibrary()
{
}

SharedLibrary::SharedLibrary()
{
}

SharedLibrary::~SharedLibrary()
{
}
```

SharedLibrary.h:

```
#pragma once

class SharedLibrary
{
public:
    const char * GetString();
    SharedLibrary();
    ~SharedLibrary();
};
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := SharedLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SharedLibrary.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Step 2**

I then compiled this shared library using the command *ndk-build*, which gives me a file *libSharedLibrary.so*

**Step 3**

I then created a Visual Studio project: File -> New -> Project -> Cross Platform -> Android -> Basic Application (Android, Ant). This project compiles and runs fine.

**Step 4**

The next step is where I am stuck: I need to somehow link the libSharedLibrary.so file to the Visual Studio project. I couldn't find anything in the project options of the Visual Studio project which allows me to do this.

So, here is my question:
How do I have to setup my Visual C++ cross platform Android project in order to link a shared object (*.so) to it?

This is my first stackoverflow post, so feel free to correct me, if I did anything wrong in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investing a stupidly large amount of time, I found the solution (thanks Microsoft for not documenting this functionality anywhere...):

- Open the Visual Studio solution
- Go to the Android Packaging Project
- Right-click on the project, then choose 'Add' -> 'New Folder'
- Name the new folder 'libs' (this naming is mandatory!)
- Create a subfolder for each targeted processor architecture (for example 'armeabi-v7a')
- Drag and drop the respective *.so file into these subfolders

When compiling the project, the 'libs' folder and its content get copied into the compiled *.apk file.

Hope this helped out somebody!

Comment: after 5 hours, i found this post. Thanks a lot